Swapping Nodes in Pairs in java
I am solving this question on leetcode and i have been having issues: here's my code:
Definition for singly-linked list:
class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode() {}
    ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }  
}
 
class Solution {
    public ListNode swapPairs(ListNode head) {
        if(head == null || head.next == null) {
            return head;
        }
        ListNode temp = new ListNode(0);
        temp.next = head;
        ListNode prev = temp;

        while(head != null && head.next != null) {
            ListNode firstNode = head;
            ListNode secondNode = head.next;

            prev.next = secondNode;
            firstNode.next = secondNode.next;
            secondNode.next = firstNode;

            prev = firstNode;
            head = firstNode.next;
        }
        return temp.next;
    }
}

It shows an error constantly saying:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'ListNode ListNode.deserialize(java.lang.String)'
at Deserializer.toListNode(Unknown Source)
at line 82, Driver.main

I thought it was because i defined the main function too. But Nope. Help me understand this, how can i solve this issue.
expecting an output for the linked list: 1->2->3->4 as 2->1->4->3

For future reference, when a question is related to a web page, it would be polite, and possibly helpful, to include a link to that page. As far as I can tell, the web page for this problem is https://leetcode.com/problems/swap-nodes-in-pairs/description/

from the [tag:dsa] tag description: "DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm) is a public-key signature algorithm defined by NIST. Do NOT use this tag for general "Data Structures and Algorithms" questions." (emphasis added - that description should even be presented when adding tags...)

This is because you are not supposed to uncomment the definition of ListNode. It is given to you by the "driver" part of the application (which contains a main function that tests your implementation). The comment is there just for your documentation.
In reality, the ListNode class has some more methods than the ones shown in the comment: the deserialize method is one of them, hence the error you get about the missing method.
The comment shows you only those methods of ListNode that are relevant to you. The rest of the class's definition is purely for the use of LeetCode.

There are many roads that lead to Rome, surely the one that follows these lines is not the most optimal, but it may serve as a starting point.
ListNode swapPairs( ListNode head ) {
   if( head == null || head.next == null ) {
      return head;
   }

     // the following lines create a list, and load all nodes into it.
   List<ListNode> lista = new ArrayList<>();
   lista.add( head );
   while( head.next != null ) {
      lista.add( head.next );
      head = head.next;
   }

   for( int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i += 2 ) {
        
        // in this line, we assign to the last node of the previous iteration, its new “next”.
      if( i > 1 ) lista.get( i - 2 ).next = lista.get( i + 1 );

        // we proceed to exchange references to “next”.
      ListNode a = lista.get( i );
      ListNode b = lista.get( i + 1 );
      a.next = b.next;
      b.next = a;
   }

     // we return the second member of the list, which now becomes “head”.
   return lista.get( 1 );
}


The OP's solution is also correct (they just needed to remove their definition of class ListNode). How is this one better than the OP's?

Thanks, I saw your answer, but in it you did not mention that the OP's code was correct, and my poor brain was left with the idea that it was not.
